# Lifetime of an OrganizationServiceContext - CRM Dynamics 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

This is more of a non-tech question.

We intend to use OrganizationServiceContext with Linq as opposed to calling OrganizationServiceProxy.

My question is: what should the lifetime of the context be? Should it instantiated once per method or can you keep it around for the life of the web application using a singleton approach?

What would the pros/cons be? Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should never keep a datacontext around for the life of a web application. The application lifecycle is managed outside of your code.

There is also a world of pain around saving changes when other users are saving at the same time. Datacontexts should always be managed only for the life of the request and running save changes should never save bits and pieces from other people's request as they are processing.

If you want to reduce reads, then use caching. 
If you want to manage concurrency use transactions with a unit of work.

Comment: That's a good point on 'saving changes'. Like most other CRMs, we'll have at least 20 people using the system at a time. Thanks Gats + Matt

Comment: Just wondering, what are the cons to creating a context per unit of work or per method?

Comment: One per unit of work requires a little more engineering and cleverer design. The disadvantage is it can lead you to complex scenarios such as inversion of control (fashionable, but beware as threading issues can pop up without you knowing). Put simply, unit of work requires more engineering, per method approach is simpler to manage, but can lead to spaghetti code and a very significant increase in database traffic. There is no simple answer, but for websites that need to perform with high traffic you will have to look at unit of work as an option.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand a little on Gats' answer, which is entirely correct, we create new context objects pretty much for each separate method we have. Even for Silverlight, where we know we're running for one user at a time, managing what is in the context at any time is just too painful just to avoid creating a new context object.